# wxPython change mouse cursor to notify a long running operation

Tags: python, wxpython, mouse-cursor

I am building a Python program that searches things on a remote website.
Sometimes the operation takes many seconds and I believe that the user will not notice the  status bar message "Search Operation in progress".
Therefore, I would like to change the mouse cursor to highlight that the program is still waiting for a result.

This is the method I am using:

```
def OnButtonSearchClick( self, event ):
        """
        If there is text in the search text, launch a SearchOperation.
        """
        searched_value = self.m_search_text.GetValue()

        if not searched_value:
            return

        # clean eventual previous results
        self.EnableButtons(False)
        self.CleanSearchResults()

        operations.SearchOperation(self.m_frame, searched_value)
```

I tried two different approaches, both before the last line:

- wx.BeginBusyCursor()
- self.m_frame.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_WAIT))

None of them are working.

I am using KDE under GNU/Linux. This does not work under Gnome, too

Any hints? Thank you

Comment: SetStockCursor should work. Have you tried any of the other default cursors? Perhaps the CURSOR_WAIT one is unavailable on your particular flavor of Linux.

Comment: I am using SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_WAIT)), sorry for the typo, I corrected the question. Yes, I am trying other cursors, none of the are working.

Comment: Focus could be an issue.  You're setting the cursor for something other than the class where the event handler is defined (what is `self.m_frame`?)  It could differ by platform, but the wx.Window you set the cursor for generally has to have focus, and the mouse pointer has to be over it for the set cursor to appear.

Comment: self.m_frame is the wx Frame of the GUI. I am not directly inheriting wx.Frame for my classes (I am using XRC and prefer to work in this way). The mouse pointer is (obviously) over the frame while I am trying this code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked Robin Dunn, the maker of wxPython about this, and it looks like this should work, but doesn't. However, if you call the panel's SetCursor(), it DOES work or so I'm told. Here's an example you can try:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Tutorial")

        # Add a self.panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        btn = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Change Cursor")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.changeCursor)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(btn)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def changeCursor(self, event):
        """"""
        myCursor= wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_WAIT)
        self.panel.SetCursor(myCursor)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I confirm that the example given works. But on my program, if I try to use the panel instead of the frame, the mouse pointer is changed only if the cursor has the focus on the panel and not on any wx widget. Therefore, it works for very small zones of the GUI.

Comment: with "small zones", I mean about 5% of the whole window :)

Comment: What sorts of widgets are we talking about? You might want to look at using wx.BusyInfo instead of using the mouse cursor if that's going to be problematic. There's an example here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/26/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll give it a try. For a better explanation: http://i42.tinypic.com/5bibk.png this is a screenshot of my program. The red-colored zones are the zones in which the cursor changes, if I use panel.SetCursor(myCursor). If the mouse has the focus on any other area of the GUI, the cursor does not change

Comment: Ok, I don't need the BusyInfo because I am using threads and don't want to block the GUI. I just would like to let the user know that the operation is still running. Is my problem related to a wxPython bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure. I added a text control to my example on my machine and then changed the cursor and it stayed changed no matter where I moved it in my application. If that's not happening for you, then you're either doing something unusual or there really is a bug. I would ask on the wxPython mailing list and provide a simple runnable example that demonstrates the issue. Sorry I wasn't of more help.

Comment: It's worth pointing out, that with wxpython 4 `wx.StockCursor` is deprecated and you should use `wx.Cursor` instead. If you set the cursor for a panel, it is only for that panel, if you set it for `self`, then it applies to the whole application.